# Wait for completion of last statement before moving to next

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

I have been working on a library for Android. The library has a method which fetches data from a web service and puts it in a database. The fetching part is, of course, not done on the main thread. Here's a sample method:

```
public void fetchData() {
    remoteTable.get(new TableOperationCallback<TEntity>() {
        public void onCompleted(TEntity entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (exception == null) {
                 //CALBACK RECEIVED
                 //Put data in local database.
            }
        });
}
```

Now, somewhere else in my app, where the library is being consumed, I do something like this to refresh the data:

```
public void refreshData(){
    mylibrary.fetchData();
    List<MyItems> mList = localtable.getItems();
}
```

Here, the first statement will go and fetch the data on background thread. So, the second statement will be executed even before the data is actually fetched. How do I get around this? I want the second statement to be executed only after the callback of the first is complete.

**Edit:** If it matters, the method `refreshData` is not in any activity. I put that method in a separate class (and called it `ViewModel` - .NET habit!).

Comment: use asyncTask for that!

Comment: I have been looking into it. However, the Azure SDK (which is fetching my data) already uses the asynctask inside. Would it be okay to wrap it in another asynctask? Also, could you give an example?

Comment: The SDK is using asyncTask for it'w own working, apart from that what you need is another thing. You can use asyncTask for your own piece of code too.

Comment: @Saqib Okay! So, by the design, should AsyncTask implementation be in the library or the app? Do I need to make any modifications in the library method?

Comment: depending on where you are updating (refreshing) the view, there you need to use asyncTask, moreover using asyncTask in library may not give you enough scope to interact with outer methods, so use it in your piece of code, call lib method in background (if that's what it's doing) and then on it's completion get response and update your view or whatever process is based on

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this link
[Android Update Current Activity From Background Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616288/android-update-current-activity-from-background-thread)

You basically want a Callback interface. When the task in the library completes, then you do what you have to do

Comment: Looks like AsyncTask is _the_ way to go. However, I don't understand the answer completely. If you could elaborate it in the context of my code, it would be great! Also, see the edit in question.